# FreeBSD restore of /rescue

Tags: backup, freebsd, rsync, restore, tar

I'm running a restore from a previous backup of my FreeBSD system, and run into trouble when restoring `/` (excluding mount-points). The problem is that `/rescue` fills the `/` partition (to the extent that I can't restore my entire `/` partition) by taking up more place than it originally did.

I suppose it's because `/rescue` contains links and not files, and that files, not links, are restored into my `/` partition. I've tried restoring with both `tar` and `rsync`:

```
( cd /mybak/ ; tar --one-file-system -cvf - . ) | ( cd /newroot/ ; tar -xpf - . )
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -va --delete --one-file-system  /mybak/ /newroot/
```

Both methods lead to my problem. What can I do to properly restore (or initially backup) the `/` partition, including `/rescue`, so that the restore doesn't take up more disk space than the original?

Comment: After some researching, it looks like this could be solved with `rsync` and its `-H` flag to preserve hardlinks. Any comments to this?

Comment: My comment is if you can't fit a copy of everything in `/rescue` on your root partition you need to make bigger root partitions :-) Remember, empty disk is cheap, but full disks can be expensive (downtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you surmised, the problem here is `/rescue` doesn't contain many files - it contains one file (inode) with many names (hard links).  As a result when backing up or restoring `/rescue` you need to use software that's aware of hard links.

For `rsync` this means the `-H` flag.

For `tar` this should not require any special magic: BSD tar (and GNU tar) are smart enough to know what a hard link is.
For other backup programs, you need to check the documentation.

---

If you're using the regular Unix tools to make backups of your system (and grabbing whole filesystems) you may be better off using [`dump`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dump&sektion=8) and [`restore`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=restore&sektion=8). Aside from the ability to use UFS snapshots, there are other advantages to the more traditional utilities.